# Copy table with custom type from one schema to another

Tags: postgresql

I want to copy data from one table in schema "test" to another table in schema "public". Both tables are identical, but the field "type" is a custom type named "item_type". The types are defined within their schema. Both types are also the same, except they belong to two different schemas.

What I tried:

```
INSERT INTO public.item
SELECT itemid, collectionid, signature, CAST(type AS public.item_type), status
FROM test.item
WHERE status like 'OK%'
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type test.item_type to item_type
LINE 2: SELECT itemid, collectionid, signature, CAST(type AS pu...
```

How can I solve this?

Edit:

The custom type looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE test.item_type AS ENUM
    ('image', 'audio', 'video', 'application', 'text');
```

Comment: so the problem is that you have a custom types named `item_type` in schemas test and public, and table `test.item` uses type `test.item_type` , table `public.item` uses `public.item_type` ?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis this is correct

Comment: Would you provide a definition for `test.item_type` so I can build you an example?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis I added the definition for test.item_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `test.item_type` is a custom type, the PostgreSQL doesn't have knowledge of how it should convert it to a different custom type `public.item_type`.

You must provide instructions for the PostgreSQL how to convert from one type to another.

One way is to create a function for that:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.test_item_type_2_public(test.item_type) 
  returns public.item_type
  language sql
AS $$
SELECT $1::text::public.item_type;
$$;
```

Later you can use it to provide a valid value for the `public.item`:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.item
SELECT itemid, collectionid, signature, public.test_item_type_2_public(i.type), status
FROM test.item i
WHERE status like 'OK%';
```

To be able to simply cast, you must define a new CAST (see the [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html) ).

```sql
CREATE CAST (test.item_type AS public.item_type)
    WITH FUNCTION public.test_item_type_2_public;
```

That way define how the `test.item_type` should be converted to `public.item_type`.

Now the query

```sql
INSERT INTO public.item
SELECT itemid, collectionid, signature, CAST(type AS public.item_type), status
FROM test.item
WHERE status like 'OK%';
```

runs without errors.

Feel free to explore full test case at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dMLlsTpa)

Lastly I'd like to suggest of not using `private.item_type` at all. Why not create a table `private.item` with type of `public.item_type`?.. It seems unnecessary...

Comment: The way OP has it set up, schemas are independent and self-contained: you can safely dump, migrate and restore them without having to keep track of and drag along anything custom from outside just that one schema.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and writing an answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to [Julius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053655/julius-tuskenis)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149473/5298879):
it seems most convenient if you just use the intermediate cast directly in your `insert`, whenever you deal with directly mappable types:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.item
SELECT itemid, collectionid, signature, type::text::public.item_type, status
FROM test.item
WHERE status like 'OK%'
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Technically, there's no difference if you do that or (re)define all your casts before copying the data over. If that's a one-off job, those definitions only add extra steps.

If you do want to set them up, you can actually get away *without* (explicit) casting entirely, and save some (re)definitions thanks to a single, [polymorphic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) function: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bqGA5k4R)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION to_public_item_type_casts(anyelement) RETURNS public.item_type
LANGUAGE SQL AS $f$ SELECT $1::text::public.item_type $f$;

CREATE CAST (test.item_type AS public.item_type) 
WITH FUNCTION to_public_item_type_casts AS IMPLICIT;

--if another schema clone comes in, you don't need a new function, only another cast
CREATE CAST (some_new_schema.item_type AS public.item_type) 
WITH FUNCTION to_public_item_type_casts AS IMPLICIT;
```

[`AS IMPLICIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html#id-1.9.3.58.6) lets PostgreSQL detect and use the cast on its own, letting you simply

```sql
INSERT INTO public.item
SELECT * FROM test.item
WHERE status like 'OK%'
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and for your additions to the other answer.